# Want to handle a firebase auth error, if a user exists for Google SignIn, but not for Email/Password

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

If user has logged in via google account, and tries to sign in via Email/Password authentication, with the same google account. Throws a wrong password exception.

> FirebaseAuthException ([firebase_auth/wrong-password] The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.)

Is there a way of getting a specific error that I can handle to direct the user to use Google signIn instead of Email/Password.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You could write a [backend function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) to check if a user with that email has logged in with google before, but I don't think that it's worth it. I would probably just show a dialog / snack bar that asks the user if they want to log in with google instead.

Comment: @HannesHultergård Okay but how would we know if this is a wrong password error, or wrong sign-in error. 
For now I'm only checking if the user exists on backend, then try logging in via Google but even that makes no sense.

Comment: You can't as far as I know. The best solution is probably to just remind the user that they might want to log in with google instead of email and password.

Comment: @HannesHultergård thanks anyway.